# Tridion 2013 sp1 , Not able to add/delete component links in XPM / Experience Manager View

Tags: experience-manager, dwt, 2013-sp1

I want to add new component links using XPM view but I am not able to get that option. I am able to edit the fields of the component links. Here is my main component xml structure and DWT code.

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:e5063cee-b6c6-4005-9312-ce0a969f0c35">
    <title xmlns="uuid:e5063cee-b6c6-4005-9312-ce0a969f0c35">xpm new title</title>
    <complink xmlns="uuid:e5063cee-b6c6-4005-9312-ce0a969f0c35" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:61-107006" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="XPMComponentLink"></complink>
    <complink xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:61-107006" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></complink>
</Content>
```

Here is the component link xml

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:e5063cee-b6c6-4005-9312-ce0a969f0c35">
    <childtitle>testtitle</childtitle>
    <childimage xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:61-85782" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="35311-GE-Retail-Lighting-101-eBook-284x95.jpg"></childimage>
</Content>
```

### DWT Code

```
<div>
@@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.title")@@
@@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
<h3>@@Component.Fields.title@@</h3>
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.complink" -->
@@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.complink")@@
@@FieldValueStartMarker(TemplateRepeatIndex)@@
 @@RenderComponentPresentation(Field,GenerateCompLink)@@
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
</div>
```

### DWT code of GenerateCompLink

```
<div>
@@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.childtitle")@@
@@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
<h3>@@Component.Fields.childtitle@@</h3>
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
@@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.childimage")@@
@@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
 <img src="@@Component.Fields.childimage@@" tridion:type="Multimedia"/> 
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
</div>
```

Can somebody please suggest what I need to do so that I am able to add/delete the component links ?

Comment: I was finally able to make it work by tweaking my Html structure a bit. I have added the updated DWT code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated DWT code

### Main DWT

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.complink" -->
@@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.complink")@@
@@FieldValueStartMarker(TemplateRepeatIndex)@@
<div>
 @@RenderComponentPresentation(Field,GenerateCompLink)@@
</div>
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

### GenerateCompLink DWT

```
@@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.childtitle")@@
@@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
@@Component.Fields.childtitle@@
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
@@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.childimage")@@
@@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
<img src="@@Component.Fields.childimage@@" tridion:type="Multimedia"/>
@@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
```